# Sendmail is not working to when external IP is trying to connect

Tags: centos, smtp, centos7, sendmail

I have CentOS with following for sendmail

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Name=MTA')dnl
```

Where i need a remote location device to send SMTP mail. But the remote location always getting Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host. Temporary i disable the firewall/iptables but even though it just get connection refused.

how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7.

```
Step 1: sudo yum install sendmail sendmail-cf
Step 2: vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
dnl #DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Name=MTA')dnl
Step 3: cd /etc/mail/; sudo make -C /etc/mail
Step 4: systemctl restart sendmail
```

TEST: telnet remoteip 25

```
Escape character is '^]'
```

Show domain name of email root@iam.example.com:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 iam.example.com localhost localhost.example
```